# Adding Bootstrap code completion to Intellij project

Tags: intellij-idea, twitter-bootstrap-3, code-completion

All,

Using Intellij IDEA Ultimate 14.1.4. and trying to add Bootstrap 3 code completion to my project.  I've downloaded the Bootstrap 3 plugin.

My project structure looks like this ...

```
MyProject
    - app
        - views
            index.html
    - public
        - css
            - bootstrap.min.css
        - ...
    - server.js
```

When I try to type in a bootstrap class in index.html such as class="col-sm-2", code completion does not work.

However, if I were to move my public\css folder directly under my project folder like so:

```
MyProject
    - app
    - css
        - bootstrap.min.css
    - ...
```

Now code completion for Bootstrap works when typing in index.html.  What gives?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it may be the location of the html page that's causing the problem.  I put an html file in both app/views/ and public/.  The public directory's html file received code completion, while the app/views directory did not.